# CSS style not working in exported runnable jar in javafx

Tags: css, netbeans, javafx

I am starting to make a small program using JavaFX and CSS file for the style I change the background when I run the program from NetBeans it works fine but when I run it from the jar file that NetBeans created in "dist" folder the background disappeared please I need your help

below the code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package finalfx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 */
public class FinalFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
         scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
           stage.getIcons().add(new Image("patient-icon-8.ico"));


        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    } 
}
```

//////////////////////////

CSS code

```
.root {
    -fx-background-image: url("84770f_6b54c02021f64aa38d05264a9afc3f80[1].jpg");

    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
    -fx-background-size: 1904 1001;
    -fx-background-position: center;

}
```

Comment: I tried this and still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Where is your css file sitting compared to your local .jpg files?

../ to take you up out of the folder the css is in

../images/ to go into the images folder

-fx-background-image: url("
../images/84770f_6b54c02021f64aa38d05264a9afc3f80[1].jpg");

Comment: In the same folder

Comment: Do you recomend separate the folders

Comment: It was an assumption I made that if it is not seeing the images they were in a different folder. sorting your files into folders may make your life easier however.